# PHP & mysqli: What is the difference between persistent connection and interactive?

Tags: php, mysqli, persistent-connection, interactive-mode

What are the differences between the following:

```
// Persistent connection
$mysqli->real_connect("p:" . $host, $user, $pass, $db, null, null, 0);
```

and

```
// Interactive connection
$mysqli->real_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, null, null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE);
```

or even this one...

```
// Interactive AND persistent
$mysqli->real_connect("p:" . $host, $user, $pass, $db, null, null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just my interpretation of the docs...

Persistent connections are kept open indefinitely.  Non-persistent connections are not.

The [mysql_pconnect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) docs are a little more clear than the real_connect() docs:

> mysql_pconnect() acts very much like mysql_connect() with two major differences.
>
> First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.
>
> Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use ( mysql_close() will not close links established by mysql_pconnect()).
>
> This type of link is therefore called 'persistent'.

Regarding [MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/apis-php-mysqli.constants.html):

> MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE
>
> Allow **interactive_timeout** seconds (instead of **wait_timeout** seconds) of inactivity before closing the connection. The client's session wait_timeout variable will be set to the value of the session interactive_timeout variable.

Normally, non-persistent connections are closed after the number of seconds specified by the **wait_timeout** variable.  With this flag, they are instead closed after the number of seconds specified by the **interactive_timeout** variable.

By my interpretation, that means that the **MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE** does not change the behavior of a *persistent* connection.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the first one mysqli tries to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password (NOT PORT). If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.

The connection to the SQL server will NOT be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use.

Comment: Although a bit helpful, this answer isn't detailed enough for me to upvote it. But thanks for your answer!